# is there any possible way to exctract the number from dictionary by only using regex

Tags: python

```
{"orders": [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},
            {"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":648},
            {"id":649},{"id":650},{"id":651},{"id":652},{"id":653}
            ]
 }
```

need to extract only numbers by using regex in python

I try to address the numbers but I can't i just want the number in the list

Comment: What? It's not even remotely clear what you're asking for... why would you use regex for this? There aren't any strings of digits on which to match. Just access the integers directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question as written is very difficult to interpret and answer. Please [review this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can edit/update your answer, including a description of what you have tried so far and why it's not working.

Comment: ddejohn yes bro I understand what you said. but this is my assessment they want me to get this number only by using regex I think is there any possible way to change all that to a string .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex isn't appropriate here, but you can get all the `id` numbers with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> d = {"orders":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":648},{"id":649},{"id":650},{"id":651},{"id":652},{"id":653}]}
>>> [o["id"] for o in d["orders"]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653]
```

If what you have is a *string*, luckily it's valid JSON, so use `json.loads` to turn it into a dictionary:

```
>>> j = '''{"orders": [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},
...             {"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":648},
...             {"id":649},{"id":650},{"id":651},{"id":652},{"id":653}
...             ]
...  }'''
>>> import json
>>> [o["id"] for o in json.loads(j)["orders"]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653]
```

Comment: yes your  answer is correct but they want me to get this number by using regex is there any possible way to get  same output by using regex... tnx bro

Comment: tnx for the idea bro after we changing the entire data into a string we can use regex

Comment: Use `json.loads`.  If someone gave you that string and told you that you *have* to use a regex to extract the numeric data, kick them in the shins and run away.